# Not receiving WM_DPICHANGED in SDL application

Tags: python, winapi, sdl, pysdl2

I'm trying to write a DPI aware application for Windows 10 with SDL2 using the PySDL2 bindings. For now I don't care about supporting any other operating systems or Windows versions older than the Anniversary Update. The problem is, that **I don't receive the WM_DPICHANGED message** that I need to resize the window when dragging between monitor with different scaling factors.

I used the Windows API to set the whole process as per-monitor-dpi-aware (v2), which seems to work mostly correct. The window content is never scaled, I can poll the current display DPI correctly and the non-client areas (e.g. the title bar) are being scaled by Windows, as they should. Other native Windows messages are also coming through, as seen with WM_MOUSEMOVE.

Versions: Windows 10 1809, Python 3.7.2, SDL 2.0.9 all 64 bit, PySDL2 0.9.6, if you want to run this locally you need to put a SDL2.dll in the "/native" subdirectory of your working directory, or modify Line 3 appropriately

```
import sys
import os
os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd() + "/native")
import sdl2.ext
import ctypes

# https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/hidpi/wm-dpichanged
WM_DPICHANGED = 0x02E0
WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200
# https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/hidpi/dpi-awareness-context
DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 = -4


def run():
    # Set the DPI Awareness Context to DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 (-4), which means we need to do all
    # DPI scaling by ourselves, EXCEPT for win32 popups and non client areas (like the title bar)
    # This function was introduced with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, so we should probably have fallbacks for
    # other operating system versions
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiawarenesscontext
    if not ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2):
        print("Unable to set DPI awareness")
    sdl2.ext.init()
    # We want to receive native WM_DPICHANGED messages, so we need to tell SDL to pass them through
    sdl2.SDL_EventState(sdl2.SDL_SYSWMEVENT, sdl2.SDL_ENABLE)
    window_width = 640
    window_height = 480
    window = sdl2.ext.Window("λ³", (window_width, window_height), flags=sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI)
    sdl2_window = window.window
    sdl2.SDL_SetWindowResizable(sdl2_window, True)

    window.show()

    running = True
    scaling_percentage = 100

    while running:
        sdl2_events = sdl2.ext.get_events()
        for sdl2_event in sdl2_events:
            if sdl2_event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
            elif sdl2_event.type == sdl2.SDL_SYSWMEVENT:
                message_pointer = sdl2_event.syswm.msg
                # Workaround because the default pointer type that is returned has no definition for the structure
                message_pointer_usable = ctypes.cast(message_pointer, ctypes.POINTER(sdl2.syswm.SDL_SysWMmsg))
                sys_wm_msg = message_pointer_usable.contents
                windows_msg = message_pointer_usable.contents.msg.win

                # On 32 bit Windows both W and L are 32 bit, on 64 bit Windows both are 64 bit
                # When values are stored in the 'high' and 'low' 'word' of W or L, we still mean the first 16 bit or
                # 16 bit after that, regardless of the platform
                l_high = (windows_msg.lParam & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16
                l_low = windows_msg.lParam & 0xFFFF
                w_high = (windows_msg.wParam & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16
                w_low = windows_msg.wParam & 0xFFFF

                if windows_msg.msg == WM_DPICHANGED:
                    print("This never gets called")
                if windows_msg.msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                    # This works
                    print(f"x {l_low}, y {l_high}")

        display_index = sdl2.SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex(sdl2_window)
        diagonal_dpi = ctypes.c_float()
        horizontal_dpi = ctypes.c_float()
        vertical_dpi = ctypes.c_float()

        # This also works and reports the percentage correctly when dragging between monitors
        sdl2.SDL_GetDisplayDPI(display_index, ctypes.byref(diagonal_dpi), ctypes.byref(horizontal_dpi), ctypes.byref(vertical_dpi))
        new_scaling_percentage = int(diagonal_dpi.value/96*100)
        if new_scaling_percentage != scaling_percentage:
            scaling_percentage = new_scaling_percentage
            print(f"Display scale changed to {scaling_percentage}%")

        sdl2.SDL_Delay(10)

    sdl2.ext.quit()
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(run())
```

Comment: Remove C tag, you posted Python code.

Comment: Is your executable manifested DPI aware?

Comment: @Jabberwocky It wasn't before, but I just tried your suggestion. I removed the call to SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext, built an exe with PyInstaller and modified the manifest with Resource Hacker to add `<dpiAwareness>PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>`. I had to add a manifest resource to the exe because the .exe.manifest file that PyInstaller generated seems to be ignored by windows. In the end the app behaved exactly the same as in the original post (meaning still no WM_DPICHANGED).

Comment: Mild success: I just tried [subclassing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-window-procedures#window-procedure-subclassing) the SDL window. My own window procedure receives WM_DPICHANGED, which leads me to believe, that SDL for some reason eats the message and doesn't pass it through as a SDL_SYSWMEVENT.